# How to put 5 divs inside 1 div?

Tags: html

I need to do this :

[image]

- div container 800x600 px
- div header 800x150 px
- div under header 800x50 px
- div menu 200x350 px
- div content 600x350 px
- div footer 800x50 px

I need to put all this 5 divs inside 1 div, each div must have different colors.

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Not sure what's the end purpose, but if the goal is only to produce that image, I'd probably play with absolute positioning... Maybe that's why I'm not getting hired as a frontend developed anymore :) Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You cannot fit 800 wide div into an 800 wide div and still have gray visible

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think the grey area is supposed to be 800px wide. It's just there for the outer width and height labels and doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Damocles However that is just a guess since OP has not posted any attempts

Comment: Well, the "DIV 600" means a height of 600px. 150+50+350+50 = 600, therefore, "DIV 600" doesn't refer to the grey area's height, but to the total height of the stacked divs. Consequentially, the "DIV 800" most likely also refers to the width of the colored divs' area, not the grey one.

Answer (score 0):

By default, block-level elements expand to 100% of the width of the containing element and their height is determined by their contents.  So most of the work here is done for you already by default.

You can set a width for the containing element and heights for the inner element.  That gets you almost all of the way there.  You just need to make the menu and content sit side by side.  You can do this with CSS grid, flexbox, `display: table`, or floats.

Also, `<div>` elements are the wrong choice here.  HTML includes a lot of different element types, such as `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<nav>`, and `<main>` that you should consider using.

Answer (score 0):

CSS grid layout is one option here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO 61631033: how-to-put-3-divs-inside-1-div</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-areas:
                    "h  h"
                    "sh sh"
                    "m  c"
                    "f  f";
                grid-template-rows:     150px 50px 350px 50px;
                grid-template-columns:  200px 600px;
                
                width:  800px;
                height: 600px;
            }
            
            #content {
                background-color:   darkgreen;
                grid-area:          c;
            }
            #footer {
                background-color:   orange;
                grid-area:          f;
            }
            #header {
                background-color:   pink;
                grid-area:          h;
            }
            #menu {
                background-color:   green;
                grid-area:          m;
            }
            #subheader {
                background-color:   yellow;
                grid-area:          sh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="subheader"></div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
            <div id="menu"></div>
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Develop this design by starting with a rectangular tesselation of the screen estate. Each rectangle represents a container element in html. Superimpose a grid with all tile borders on grid lines. The grid does not need to be equi-spaced in any dimension. This grid is the base for the `grid-template-areas` CSS property that mirrors the tesselation in an obvious way.

There are a host of additional options how to specify a grid layout, especially tuned to more regular tilings. MDN has their [own section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) on layouting with this methodology.

If support of different devices and responsive design is of primary concern, [flex layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) will suit the task better.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just assign height to each element and width as per your need, rest give `display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap` to its parent, and it will handle everything

```css
* {margin: 0; padding:0; box-sizing: border-box;}
.wrapper {max-width: 800px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;}
header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #FF009C;
  width: 100%;
}
.yellow50 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #D8FF00;
  width: 100%;
}
.blue350, .orange350 {height: 350px; width: 50%;}
.blue350 {
  background-color: #03907A;
}
.orange350 {
  background-color: #FF7E00;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0B561B;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <div class="yellow50"></div>
  <div class="blue350"></div>
  <div class="orange350"></div>
  <footer>  
</section>
```